# How to find the nearest land mark from a given longitude and latitude?

Tags: javascript, sql, php

I have a table called `osm_places` with `place_name geometry, place_type` and many other info related to the city. My database system is PostGIS.

My requirement is:

Given a latitude and longitude (which may or many not be the exact lat and long stored in the database), I need to find the nearest city or place_name  from the table `osm_places` with the help of the input latitude and longitude. Any help is highly appreciated.

Is there a nearest neighbor implementation in php available for this or SQL to handle this?

Comment: Need more information about your setup. Is it PostGIS or Microsoft or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in pgRouting called find_node_by_nearest_link_within_distance(), which does exactly what you need. See http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/a-look-at-pgrouting-find_node_by_nearest_link_within_distance/

Answer (score 1):

**Geonames API** can also do this - you will need an account:

Live Demo
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo

Example - but you need to use your own account (replace username=demo)
http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=51.507689&lng=-0.127934&username=demo

Documentation
http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#extendedFindNearby